# Spring message appears several times during the test run

Tags: spring-boot, docker, junit, testcontainers

I am currently using spring-boot with the org.testcontainers library to pass test in docker . But I noticed that the following message appears several times :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.20.RELEASE)
```

It appears up to 4 times , 2 of them with the following message :

```
11:33:23.733 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@13ffeba4: startup date [Wed Jun 16 11:33:23 CEST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
```

Some messages that have caught my attention, first time that appears (the only one I think necessary)

```
11:31:48.515 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
11:31:49.019 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5416 ms
```

2 : It does not appear Why?

3:

```
11:35:06.738 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
11:35:06.764 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1569 ms
```

4:

```
11:36:19.343 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
11:36:19.362 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 454 ms
```

The message always pops up after a specific test, for example the third time during this test.

```java
@Category(OneTest.class)
public class PasswordEncryptionTest
{

  @Test
  public void passwordEncryptionTest()
  {
    PasswordEncryption passwordEncryption = new PasswordEncryption();
    try
    {
      String password = "passwordExample";
      
      String encrypted = passwordEncryption.encryptPassword(password.toCharArray());
      
      String decrypted = passwordEncryption.decryptPassword(encrypted.toCharArray());
      assertEquals(password, decrypted);
    }
    catch (PasswordDecryptionException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      fail(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Is this normal ? Because it is the message that appears when you start the application and that it appears 4 times, that is what I noticed.

Can it be affecting the performance of the tests?

Pd: They are messages, after passing the tests many times, in different environments, they are not the result of chance. I have seen no relationship in the times between the different appearances. (It does not follow a time pattern)

- spring-boot 1.5.20
- junit47
- org.testcontainers 1.13.0
- Docker windows 2.2.0.3

Comment: It would be good to share some part of the tests. Looks like your application restarts multiple times during tests (This may be wanted).

Comment: @Ghokun That's right, I have completed the question

Comment: Spring Test has a [Context Caching mechanism to reuse an already started TestContext](https://rieckpil.de/improve-build-times-with-context-caching-from-spring-test/). However, if you have different context configurations for your tests, Spring Test starts a new context and won't reuse an exciting one. This has an impact of our overall performance (aka. build time) of our tests.